# WebStorm Code Assistance For Global Variables

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, webstorm, code-completion

I'm working with `WebStorm` and `Parse` / `Parse-Sever`, but having an issue where code assistance is not working the `Parse` functions. It tells me

```
require() call is missing
```

for the `Parse` variable, but since `Parse` is defined globally, when I add the require, it overwrites the global variable and breaks things.

**Is there a way in `WebStorm` to enable code assistance for global variables?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using libraries that define their own global symbols, it is recommended that you add the corresponding TypeScript type definition file as a JavaScript library in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries. Click Download and search for the library you're using.

Comment: @RPK can you tell please how exactly it helped? I have `prop-types` package available globally (via webpack) under name `ReactPropTypes`. I installed `@typed/prop-types` in "Libraries" setting, named that library `ReactPropTypes`, and... nothing. WebStorm still complains about "Element is not exported" for every mention of `ReactPropTypes` in my code. How it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Ekaterina's answer. If you have defined globally `PropTypes = require('prop-types');` via webpack provide plugin for example, you can't just add library from *node_modules/prop-types/index.js* because it doesn't define any global variables except `module.exports` that doesn't help.

In this case you can create separate file

*globals.js*

```js
window.PropTypes = require('prop-types')
```

and add it as Ekaterina sayed to `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`

P.S. You don't need to import this file in any place of your code if have already set up webpack provide plugin. This file is just to show this global variables for IDE.