# WebStorm + Webpack: autocompletion for global objects

Tags: webpack, webstorm, jsdoc

I have an utilities module in my project, which is available globally through webpack's [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) under name "F". Code looks like this:

```
/** @typedef {Object} F */

/** @function F.somefunc */
export function somefunc() ...
```

I've added this module to libraries list, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38991200/3437433), so WebStorm does not complain about "missing import statement". And due to JSDoc, <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on `F.somefunc(...)` in code opens declaration of `somefunc`.

But there are still problems:

- <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on `F` itself still says "cannot find declaration to go to" – while I expect it to open a line with `@typedef {Object} F`
- autocompletion for `F` does not work even with all my JSDoc:
  [image]

I tried to add `/** @global */` directive to declaration of `F`, tried to add `/** @memberOf F */` to each function, but it does nothing.

How to make these things work?

WebStorm version is 2017.2